# I don't understand that js construction

Tags: javascript

I have code

```
 t.prototype.checkFields = function () {
      var e = this,
      t = this.$container.find('.form-fieldset'),
      a = 0;
      return t.filter(':visible').each(function (t, i) {
        var s = $(i),
        n = s.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"]'),
        r = n.data('write-id');
        - 1 === e.settings.emptyIgnoring.indexOf(r) && n.length && !n.prop('disabled') && (n.val().trim() || (a++, s.addClass('is-js-error').find('.form-fieldset__error').html('Заполните поле')))
      }),
      a
  },
```

The line write down write text with .html('Заполните поле') if input is empty but i not understand when the conditions is happened and text is wrote, i not see `if (...) then write text`.

Why addClass is with &&? What it return when class is added, true?

What is that?

I read little about prototype, see it in bootstrap and jQuery sources

```
 - 1 === e.settings.emptyIgnoring.indexOf(r)  //indexOf return r position, and is -1 if not found for example one string in another 

 && n.length // that mean that length of n is bigger than 0

 && !n.prop('disabled') //is not set attribute disabled=true is equal i think with attr('disabled')==true

 && (n.val().trim() //removes newlines, spaces and other from the beginning and end of the n value

 || (a++, //increment but why is need here

 s.addClass('is-js-error') //add class name

 .find('.form-fieldset__error') // find child element with class form-fieldset__error

 .html('Заполните поле'))) // set the html to element with class form-fieldset__error
```

The post request that is send when form submit is (the phone and email is empty bul I also write $('input').val('text'); and after send form and data is also empty)

```
  token[3853526949671]:4dd0e6e302563d00
  source:add
  captcha:Maxim
  email:asdasd@mm.nn
  private:1
  phone:
  name:
```

> I need to fill input and pass that validate function that return text that input is empty, but $('input[type=text]').val('some text'); and submit form get me the text that input is not filled with text and i think that function show that label and block form post execution

Comment: This code has been obfuscated/minified so it is harder to read. This is not a good code to learn from.

Comment: I undestand that it is Obfuscated, and I not need to learn fro it, i need to pass that problem with filling of inputs and send form. That function stop post request i think

Comment: Well, what thing you could do is rewrite the code by renaming the variables and expanding short-circuit operators in normal if/else statements.

Comment: So when trying to submit a form, the bootstrap framework comes up with a message that a form field was empty, even though the field has been filled by a piece of JavaScript code you wrote yourself. Did I rephrase your problem correctly?

Comment: yes I fill with js some inputs and with js try to click subbmit button, but some js code return message that inputs is empty (and send ajax post with empty values for that inputs and that get error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beautified version of your function with some annotations.
returns the amount of visible form-fieldsets that contain an empty text-, password- or email-input.
ignores disabled inputs, and inputs on the `emptyIgnoring`-blacklist.

made some slight changes to the code.

```
t.prototype.checkFields = function () {
    var ignore = this.settings.emptyIgnoring, 
        numEmptyInputs = 0;

    this.$container.find('.form-fieldset:visible').each(function (i, node) {
        var $node = $(node), 
            $inputs = $node.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"]'),
            writeId = $inputs.data('write-id');

        //writeId is not in the Array `settings.emptyIgnoring`
        //this node contains at least one text-, password- or email-input field
        //the input is not disabled (actually only checks the first element)
        //the input contains some none-whitespace characters
        if(ignore.indexOf( writeId ) === -1 && $inputs.length > 0 && !$inputs.prop('disabled') && !$inputs.val().trim()){
            numEmptyInputs++;
            $node.addClass('is-js-error');
            $node.find('.form-fieldset__error').html('Заполните поле');
        }
    }); 
    return numEmptyInputs;
},
```

Comment: When I need to fill all inputs and I do it with $('input').val('someval') but this function return me that some inputs are empty!! Why and how?

Comment: also is not clear why `|| (a++,` became `then begin` and the `,` where is need to be `;`

Comment: `Why and how?` I don't know. I just tried to explain the code in the minified function you posted, by converting it into a more readable code.

Comment: `also is not clear why || (a++, became then begin` I don't understand that part with 'then begin'. `return (leftPart) || (rightPart)` is the same as `if(leftPart){ return leftPart; }else{ return rightPart }` while leftPart and rightPark can be anything from a value to a condition, ... And about the `,` the comma is perfectly fine there. Call this in your dev-tools `var a = 0, _return = (a++, "doSomething()"); console.log(a, _return);` or read this [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)